# Click event only works on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

**TL;DR** - Anyone know why a click handler would only work on refresh?

If I have a function like so:

```
function selectState() {
    $('#state-select').change(function(event) {
        var state = $(this).val(); 
        $("#vmap").find(("#jqvmap1_") + (state.toLowerCase(''))).click(); 
    });
 }
```

and I have that function run like so:

```
function setClickHandlers() {
    $(document).on('click','a#reset_tracker',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get('decisiontree/reset_tracker/', function(data) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    });
    if ($('#vmap').length !== 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#vmap').bind('regionClick.jqvmap', function(event, code, region) {
                $('#state-select').val(code.toUpperCase());
            });
            selectState(); //once the map loads, we should be able to select things, right
            }, 500);     
    }
}
```

Which is then called by:

```
function setupSlide() {
    setClickHandlers();
    if ((typeof $.fn.vectorMap !== "undefined" && $.fn.vectorMap !== null) &&       
$('#vmap').length !== 0) {
         $('#vmap').vectorMap({
             map: 'usa_en',
             backgroundColor: null,
             color: '#6a1912',
             hoverColor: '#fdb33f',
             selectedColor: '#fdb33f',
             enableZoom: true,
             showTooltip: true,
             onRegionClick: function(event, code, region) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 $('#state-select').val(code.toUpperCase());
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Which is called by:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    setupSlide(); 

    $(document).on('click','.prev', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        loadSlide(prev_slide_url,{});
    });

    $(document).on('click','.next', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var answer;
        if ($(this).hasClass('button') || $(this).hasClass('button-small')) {
            answer = $(this).val();
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('arrow')) {
            answer = $('input[type=checkbox].answer:checked').val();
            if (!answer && $('input[type=checkbox]').length > 0) {
                $("p.inactive").addClass("error");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#vmap").length > 0) {
                 //for the map, the value is in the select
                 answer = $('#state-select').val();
                 if ($("#state-select").val().length === 0) {
                     $("p.inactive").addClass("error");
                     return false;
                 }

             }
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('navbutton')) {
            answer = $(this).data('val');
        }

    loadSlide(next_slide_url,{answer: answer});
    });
});
```

Why would the click method in SelectState only be invoked when the page that contains that function (namely, the page that has #vmap on it) is refreshed, rather than when the next or prev buttons (which have functionality defined in the document.ready block of code) are clicked?  Is there something special about click handlers in this sort of context?  I'm really unsure as to what is going on incorrectly.

One thing that I will add is that #jqvmap1_ refers to a path element in an SVG map, namely a map of the United States.  But since it works on refresh, I don't think that it has to do with the fact that it is a path element.

Let me know if you need additional clarification for this problem.  Apologies for the messy code.

Comment: Does the `#select_state` object exist when `selectState()` is first called?  If not, then there's nothing to install the `.change()` handler on so it doesn't get installed.

Comment: Yep.  Console.logs reveal that the state value is being stored, so the function works.  It just isn't invoking the click handler.

Comment: Break out `$("#vmap").find(("#jqvmap1_") + (state.toLowerCase('')))` seperately and see if it's finding an object.  Check the `.length()` of the resulting jQuery object to see if it's finding anything.

Comment: "works on refresh", do you mean "works after refresh"? If so, is the behaviour identical after F5 or browser's refresh button, and after  `a#reset_tracker` has been clicked?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yep, it is finding an SVG path element.  It's just that .click() that isn't correctly being applied.  Doing .trigger("click") yields nothing, too.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - Ha, I meant after, not on (too much Javascript!).  The behavior is exactly the same if you do an f5/cmd+r or click refresh in the browser (I wasn't aware there was a difference).  However, clicking reset tracker does NOT yield the correct behavior.  Is a window.location.reload not the same as refreshing a page, or is this telling us that the click handler is only being applied if the map is initialized from the get-go (rather than dynamically, as it normally happens with those .next/.prev .click() methods.)

Comment: Michael, I can't see why it should be so but *yes*, there's got to be a clue in the behavioural difference after the two types of refresh. Could it be to do with `window.location.reload();` being performed in the callback to `$.get('decisiontree/reset_tracker/');`? See what happens if you execute `window.location.reload();` directly without the `$.get(...)` wrapper.

Comment: @jfriend00, I'm probably being picky here but in your statement above, "jQuery" could be happily deleted (twice). `.click()` will fire click handler(s) regardless of how they were attached. It is indeed true that `.click()` doesn't simulate an actual mouse click insomuch as it doesn't trigger the hyperlink (href) action. The same is true of `.onclick()` in POJS. Michael, this may or may not be relevant to the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Ah, there is a click handler applied, and it is part of a JS library that I didn't include.  http://jqvmap.com/

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Hm, looks like a#reset_tracker is not the culprit, the function runs fine after invoking the window.location.reload().  Maybe it's something in the next and prev click events?  I tried commenting out the if ($("#vmap").length > 0) condition, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I didn't think a#reset_tracker would be the culprit. It was just a hope that it's behaviour might offer insight into what's going on.